# ROOM Dao ERROR: Not Sure How to handle insert method's return type & Not Sure how to handle delete method's return type

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I am giving the classes whatever I created and ,and where the error is showing.
I am unable to understand the error.

**DAO**

```
    package com.example.grocerylist
    
    import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
    import androidx.room.*
    
    @Dao
    interface GroceryDao {
    
    
        @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
        suspend fun insert(item: GroceryItems)
    
        @Delete
        suspend fun delete(item: GroceryItems)
    
        @Query("SELECT * FROM groceryItems")
        fun getAllGroceryItems(): LiveData<List<GroceryItems>>
    
    }
```

**Entity**

```
    import androidx.room.ColumnInfo
    import androidx.room.Entity
    import androidx.room.PrimaryKey
    
    
    @Entity(tableName = "groceryItems")
    data class GroceryItems(
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "ItemName") val ItemName:String,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "ItemQuantity") val ItemQuantity:Int,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "ItemPrice") val ItemPrice:Double,
    
    )
```

**ERRORS**

My gradle building is failed and the error is denoting "dao" class and the errors:

```
1. areC:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\GroceryList\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\example\grocerylist\GroceryDao.java:15: error: Not sure how to handle insert method's return type.
public abstract java.lang.Object insert(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()

2.C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\GroceryList\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\example\grocerylist\GroceryDao.java:17: error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it.
    kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super kotlin.Unit> continuation);
                                                        ^
                                     ^
 
3.C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\GroceryList\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\example\grocerylist\GroceryDao.java:21: error: Not sure how to handle delete method's return type. Currently the supported return types are void, int or Int.
    public abstract java.lang.Object delete(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
                                     ^
4.C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\GroceryList\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\example\grocerylist\GroceryDao.java:23: error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it.
    kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super kotlin.Unit> continuation);
                                                       ^
```

What i missed and what ahve to do now Please help.

I don't Know where is the problem i followed all the instruction instruction by developers official documents to create room .

**Dependenies**

dependencies {

```
 implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$rootProject.appCompatVersion"
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:$rootProject.activityVersion"

    // Dependencies for working with Architecture components
    // You'll probably have to update the version numbers in build.gradle (Project)

    // Room components
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$rootProject.roomVersion"

    // Lifecycle components
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$rootProject.lifecycleVersion"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$rootProject.lifecycleVersion"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$rootProject.lifecycleVersion"
  
    // Kotlin components
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10"
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$rootProject.coroutines"
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$rootProject.coroutines"

    // UI
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$rootProject.constraintLayoutVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$rootProject.materialVersion"

    // Testing
    testImplementation "junit:junit:$rootProject.junitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$rootProject.coreTestingVersion"
    androidTestImplementation ("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$rootProject.espressoVersion", {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$rootProject.androidxJunitVersion"
}
```

Comment: have you added dependency: `implementation "androidx.room:room-coroutines:${versions.room}"` ?

Comment: yes i have added my dependencies here

Comment: Now please see i have added my all dependencies ,where the dependency you have told i have added

Comment: You don't have such dependency in the list, please check my answer.

Comment: Upgrade your room version to latest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add dependency to the app's `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-coroutines:${rootProject.roomVersion}"
```

And then clean, sync and build the project. Make sure the `rootProject.roomVersion` is the latest available production version.

Comment: i have added that one

Comment: have you added it to your question? Can you point on what line?

Comment: Hey @Chayan have you checked my answer?

Comment: Yes @sergio u were correct, Thank u so much for your kind help .

Comment: from https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room   The artifact room-coroutines has been renamed to room-ktx following the same naming as other androidx artifacts.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by switching from kapt to ksp.

Answer (score 1):

just remove the `suspend` keyword from your insert and delete function and magically everything will start working again ...

Answer (score 0):

Even after using the `room-ktx` as answered in [Android Studio Kotlin Room database error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70527091/android-studio-kotlin-room-database-error) I ran into build errors.

I was only able to resolve it by adding the dependency of hilt in the gradle file

`implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"`
`kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"`

If you face an issue with getting the version, just put a version and AndroidStudio should autosuggest the version available